# Replacing TFS App Tier

Tags: tfs

I plan on replacing my existing app tier (TFS 2010) when upgrading to TFS 2013. I'll quiesce the services and rename the old machine from MYTFS to MYTFS_OLD. The new app tier will have a fresh, un-configured installation of TFS 2013 and will be renamed from MYTFS_NEW to MYTFS.

My question is, will it be necessary to run the ChangeServerID or RemapDB commands if the new app tier is named the same as the old one?

Comment: The process you draft here is incomplete and I can think many ways you can screw up and lose your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly you will end up with:

- A new server that's completely clean
- The 'old' database server that contains all the TFS databases.

If that's the case, you should install TFS and select 'Upgrade'. You then point your TFS Application Tier to your database server and let TFS upgrade your databases.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have both version running on the same set of databases.

Study the ALM Ranger's [Upgrade guide](https://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/) before doing anything.

Comment: I know that you can't have both versions running on the same set of databases. The old TFS app tier would be effectively disconnected from the existing data tier.

Comment: My scenario is as close as I can get to the ALM Ranger's In-Place Upgrade. Since I can't upgrade the OS on the existing AT, I have to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to run remapdbs or changeserverid commands:

- you typically need remapdbs when the server name changes which is not the case
- you should use changeserverid if you plan to clone a TFS server meaning that you have restored TFS databases to a different machine and set up another TFS instance on that machine without killing the original server. Again it's not the case from what you have described here.